# Using the mySQLi avg() function. What should my query be?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have a question, I hope somebody can help me make a query to get the avarage rating out of database table.

My database is currently set up like this: (I hope it's clear enough to understand)

The database name is 'beoordelingen'

The first table in the database is 'beoordeling' where I store the filename (file) and title (Spel) in 3 columns:

```
[ id | file | Spel ]
```

The second table in the database is 'comments' with 3 columns:

```
[ id | comment | form_id ]
```

The third table in the database is 'game_rating' with 3 columns:

```
[ id | form_id | rating ]
```

What I would like to do, is echo the avarage rating from table game_rating but I'm having problems understanding what I need to say in the query to achieve this.

I created a master page where all the game titles are displayed and made into a link on clicking this link you receive an ID and continue to the detail page.
Here is the code from the master page:

```
<?php
    //Place all data from this mySQL query in $result.
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM beoordeling");

    //While a row of data exists, put that row in $data as an associative array.
    while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        //Echo links to all the games in the MySQL database.
        echo "<a href='detail.php?id=" . $data['ID'] . "'>";

            //Echo the games name.
            echo $data['Spel'];

        echo "</a>";
        echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

And this is the detail page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
        include("dbconnect.php");
        error_reporting(E_ALL);


        if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

            //Place all data out of the database, with the ID number retrieved out of the url in $result.
            $game = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM beoordeling WHERE id = '" . $id . "'");
        }

        //While a row of data exists, put that row in $data as an associative array.        
        while($data = $game->fetch_assoc()) {
            $gameName = $data['Spel'];
            $fileName = $data['file']; 
        }

        //CommentList retrieves all comments with id = x.
        $commentList = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE form_id = '" . $id . "'"); 
    ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
        <title><?php echo $gameName; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php        
            /*  
             * 
             * @ToDo: Make point system show avarage rating
             * 
             * @ToDo: Create a webmaster page where you can add games to the list
             * and automaticly create game page.
             * 
             */

                //Retrieve the file name from the database and place it in the <embed> tags as src="...".
                echo "<embed width='800' height='512' src='{$fileName}' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'></embed><br />";



        //Echo the form with a text box and a rating box.
        echo '<div id="game_form"><form method="POST">
            <a>Leave a comment</a><br />
          <input type="text" name="comments" />
          <br /><a>Rate'.$gameName.'</a><br />  
        <select name="rategame">
          <option value="">Select...</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />   
        </form></div>';

            //Create a table with all the comments  
            echo "<div id='table_data'><table>";

            while($cdata = $commentList->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $cdata["comment"] . "</td> <br /><br />";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table></div>";

        //Submit functionality    
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        //Check if comment is entered else set it to an empty string
        if (isset($_POST['comments'])) {
            $commentText = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
        } else {
            $commentText = "";
        }

        $rate = $_POST['rategame'];

        echo $rate;

        //If user enters either rate or comment (or both) send a query to table.
        //Else only send the query with the users input which the user has entered.
        if (($rate >= 1) && ($rate <= 5)) {
            if ($commentText === "") {
                $sqlrate = "INSERT INTO game_rating (rating, form_id) VALUES ('{$rate}','{$id}')";
                $sqlcomment = ""; //Initializing to null to avoid error.
            }
            else {
                $sqlrate = "INSERT INTO game_rating (rating, form_id) VALUES ('{$rate}','{$id}')";
                $sqlcomment = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, form_id) VALUES ('{$commentText}','{$id}')";
            }   
        }
        else {
            if ($commentText !== "") {
            $sqlcomment = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, form_id) VALUES ('{$commentText}','{$id}')";
            $sqlrate = ""; //initializing to null to avoid error.
            }
        }

        //Push query to database
        if($sqlcomment) {
             $conn->query($sqlcomment); 
        }

        if($sqlrate) {
             $conn->query($sqlrate); 
        }


        //Close connection to free up resources.
        $conn->close();
        }
    ?>      
    </body>
</html>
```

So on the detail page I would like to display avarage rating for the game.
Can anyone help me make this happen ? :D Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the form_id in the game_rating table is a foreign key to table beoordeling, then this could do the trick:

```
$ratings = $conn->query(
        "SELECT AVG(rating) avg_rating " .
        "FROM game_rating WHERE form_id = '" . $id . "'");
$data = $ratings->fetch_assoc();
$avg_rating = $data['avg_rating'];
```

This `SELECT` will return one record always. It might contain the value `NULL` if no ratings are found, but you will have a record anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this! It works. I actually looked up a video on youtube for a php rating system and I got really confused when he used LEFT JOIN to join the tables. I was sure I needed this for my query so this actually is a relieve to see it wasn't really necessary.

Comment: It wasn't necessary to `join` because you already had the `id`. If, for example, you would only have had the `file` and wanted to get the ratings linked to that, a `join` would be called for. Groetjes.